# List all folders that are direct children Google drive API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to list all folders that are at the root of a teamdrive using the google api php client. The perans i'm using look like this:

```
$optParams = array(
  'driveId' => "<ID OF TEAM DRIVE>",
  'pageSize' => 100,
  'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => true,
  'supportsAllDrives' => true,
  'corpora' => "drive",
  'fields'=>'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  'q' => ["mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", "'<ID OF TEAM DRIVE>' in parents"]

);
```

The problem is that this lists all the sub-folders as well and not just the folders in the root of that team drive.

This feels like it should be easy but i'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I did solve this by removing DriveId, copora and the mimeType.
My guess is that this statement (which I did not find a documentation on) means one thing OR another thing and not one thing AND another thing.

```
["mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", "'<ID OF TEAM DRIVE>' in parents"]
```

So what worked for me was:

```
  $optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 100,
  'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => true,
  'supportsAllDrives' => true,
  'fields'=>'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  'q' => "'<DRIVE ID>' in parents"

);
```

Answer (score 0):

[user3477740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3477740/user3477740), you were very close.

Place your entire query inside a single string like below, and (I strongly suggest) separate your logic inside parenthesis:

`'q' => "(trashed = false) and (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder') and ('<DRIVE ID>' in parents)"`

And thanks to you for showing me the easy way to reference google drive children within a google drive folder - it's not well documented in Google Drive V3